# custom xml parser class with completion block

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, objective-c-blocks

I'm creating a xml parser class with TBXML. I'd like the class to load an xml doc, traverse through it, and return an array of strings to populate a table. This should take place in a background thread so it does block the UI. I'd like to add a completion block so the table's data source array is set when the xml parsing is complete.

How do I implement the completion block? Here's what I have so far:

Parser.m

```
- (NSMutableArray *)loadObjects
{
    // Create a success block to be called when the asyn request completes
    TBXMLSuccessBlock successBlock = ^(TBXML *tbxmlDocument) {
        NSLog(@"PROCESSING ASYNC CALLBACK");

        // If TBXML found a root node, process element and iterate all children
        if (tbxmlDocument.rootXMLElement)
            [self traverseElement:tbxmlDocument.rootXMLElement];
    };

    // Create a failure block that gets called if something goes wrong
    TBXMLFailureBlock failureBlock = ^(TBXML *tbxmlDocument, NSError * error) {
        NSLog(@"Error! %@ %@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
    };

    // Initialize TBXML with the URL of an XML doc. TBXML asynchronously loads and parses the file.
    tbxml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"XML_DOC_URL"]
                               success:successBlock
                               failure:failureBlock];
    return self.array;
}


- (void)traverseElement:(TBXMLElement *)element
{    
    do {
        // if the element has child elements, process them
        if (element->firstChild) [self traverseElement:element->firstChild];

        if ([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
            TBXMLElement *title = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"title" parentElement:element];
            NSString *titleString = [TBXML textForElement:title];
            [self.array addObject:titleString];
        };

        // Obtain next sibling element
    } while ((element = element->nextSibling));
}
```

TableViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Parser *parser = [[Parser alloc] init];
    self.products = [parser loadObjects]; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this, you'll get an empty array, right? That's because `loadObjects` is not blocking and returns before it could complete its task.

Now, you want your `viewDidLoad` to return immediately so your table can display. So in your `TableViewController`, you want a callback that gets called and manages the update after your empty table is displayed. The standard technique is to use delegation. In `Parser.h` define

```
@protocol ParserProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)parserDidFinishLoading;
@end
```

in the Parser-interface add

```
@property id<ParserProtocol> delegate;
```

Finish your `successBlock` with the line

```
[self.delegate parserDidFinishLoading];
```

then make TableViewController conforming to `ParserProtocol` and add the Parser as a property:

```
@property Parser* parser;
```

in TableViewController.m replace

```
Parser *parser = [[Parser alloc] init];
self.products = [parser loadObjects];
```

with

```
self.parser = [[Parser alloc] init];
self.products = [self.parser loadObjects];
```

and add

```
-(void)parserDidFinishLoading{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The `self.products` points to the now modified `array` property of `Parser`. So no additional setup should be needed.

Good luck, Peter.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Only two things: 1)loadObjects is still returning an empty array, so instead I simply set `self.products = self.parser.array` property rather than the returned array. 2) I'm getting some really strange latency in between `self.tableview reloadData` and `cellForRow...`. It's causing my table to not be updated until like 15 seconds after parserDidFinishLoading is called.

Comment: I figured out the delay. `reloadData` was called in the background thread while in the delegate method. I had to replace `reloadData` with `[[self tableView] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];`

Comment: Is it ok to set a property to another class's property `self.products = self.parser.array`?

Comment: Yes, setting properties like this is perfectly ok. `self.parser.array` calls the getter of `array` and that returns a pointer. `self.products =` calls the setter of `products` with that pointer as argument.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice the potential issue with the threads, good point. But I probably would call `performSelectorOnMainThread:` in the successBlock, e.g. with `parserDidFinishLoading` of the `delegate`. That way, the responsibility of switching threads is that of the `Parser` object alone. The ViewController should not know about other threads.